# The execution of the while loop after every n steps

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, applescript

How do I make it so that in the for loop, after every 7 times the loop is executed, a certain action is executed, and then the loop continues to be executed for 7?

Now I have a loop performing some actions using Python + applescript. 
I tried using while to make a condition that should be executed after every 7 steps and then continue the loop with excel. The cycle works, everything is fine. But at the moment when the while starts executing-it doesn't want to loop from the beginning, it wants to keep executing the while because of the count variable that takes rows from the excel file. 
How to fix it?

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import xlrd

def main():
    apple_script = '''
         code
       '''
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    count = 1
    for cell in sheet.col(0):
        p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate(apple_script)
        count += 1
        while count >= 7:
            app_script = '''
                 code
                '''
            p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate(app_script)
            break
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you heard of modulo before? I think that could help you do something every seventh time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count=1
while count >= 7:
   if count % 7 == 0:
      print(count)
   count = count + 1
```

Output:

```
7
14
21
28
35
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, keep a counter per loop, then you can %7 that number and do a process during every 7 loops:

```
x=0
while x < 50:
   if x % 7 == 0:
      print(f"Loop for Every Seven: {x}")
   x = x + 1
```

output:

```
Loop for Every Seven: 0
Loop for Every Seven: 7
Loop for Every Seven: 14
Loop for Every Seven: 21
Loop for Every Seven: 28
Loop for Every Seven: 35
Loop for Every Seven: 42
Loop for Every Seven: 49
```